# Optimal settings for madVR for this PC

Tags: codec, 4k-resolution

CPU: Ryzen 5 1600 stock cooler
GPU: GIgabyte GTX 1050ti 4GB OC Gaming
Motherboard: Gigabyte AB-350 Gaming 3
Monitor: Full HD
Connection: HDMI

Now I know my motherboard and CPU supports 4k video playback, but I am not sure about the GPU.

My monitor is not 4k, but from what I know, this is more related to hardware. I am fine with Full HD, but I want to see if my system can handle 4K or not. I tried some samples and they are super choppy on VLC. They work better on MPC-HC with the CCCP codec pack. I have downloaded the madVR codec cause I heard it is the best codec. However, I am not sure about what settings will be optimal for my PC without causing any BSOD(GSOD) or any other issues.

Comment: Mad VR is more for upscaling. than running 4k natively

Comment: @JourneymanGeek So why my 4K video playback is choppy? I thought I had to use madVR.

Comment: Wrong buffer settings in VLC can make a large resolution video choppy even if the hardware supports it. And no, bigger buffer is not better in VLC, in fact its a killer for framerates. Too small isn't good either, and the default is not good either.

Comment: @LPChip what about MPC-HC with CCCP?

Comment: I have insufficient experience with that.I just wanted to point out what the choppy VLC experience likely is caused by.